# How to change the module name of a driver in Linux?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, compatibility

We have two Adaptec RAID controllers on our CentOS 5 server, Adaptec 5805 and Adaptec 8805.

These controllers require two versions of the same AACRAID driver to be used, because the first driver version that supports Adaptec 8805 on RHEL 5 is v1.2.1-40300, and the latest driver version that supports the older Adaptec 5805 is 1.1.7-29100.

The drivers are in form of kernel modules (`aacraid.ko`).

Both drivers have the same module name `aacraid`, so both of them cannot used at the same time. However, if there is a way to change the module name of one of them, that would be possible.

How can the module name of a device driver in Linux be changed? It may be possible to recompile one of the drivers from source. I assume that there may be one or two things that should be changed in the source code to change the module name. What are the things that should be changed in the driver source code?

Comment: When built, the module's name is specified in the `Makefile`/`Kbuild` file. So, if you may recompile the driver from the sources, then just edit corresponded file. But it is most likely that name of the module is not the only thing which should be changed for allow two instances of the driver to work at the same time. If the driver registers some **named** device in the kernel, then you need to make this name different in two instances. Generally, you may fix source code iteratively: Try to load both drivers and see what is wrong. Then fix the error and repeat loading.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you should post that as an answer.